# Not able to create new application/project with Angular (ng new ) Angular CLI v7.0.6

Tags: angular

```
ng new FirstDataApp
? Would you like to add Angular routing? (y/N) events.js:167
     throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
```

**Error**:

> read EINVAL
>   ted 'error' event at:
>   at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
>   at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

Comment: what version of Node and Npm do you have? The ng-CLI v7 needs: Node 10.9 or later installed

Answer (score 0):

This may have to do something with the environment configuration that you have. The CLI v 7.0.6 expects you to have node version 10.9 or later, TypeScript 3.1. Please check the node and npm versions and make sure you have the right versions installed. Install your angular cli and then go ahead to generate the project.

> If you get an error installing the CLI, this is an issue with your local npm setup on your machine, not a problem in Angular CLI.